# Dismissing AVPlayerViewController doesn't 'kill' the object - it's persisting

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I am playing videos that are in my app bundle.

They are playing correctly.

However, when I call to dismiss the AVPlayerViewController, it visibly is removed from the view hierarchy but, if I turn off the iOS device and turn it back on again, on the lock screen there is a media control showing that video and a 'play' button.

If you touch play you only get the audio and no video.

My problem is I don't understand why the 'dismiss' is not completely 'killing' the player when I'm done with it.

Here is the presentation code:

```swift
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: type)

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

let player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(VideoLibraryViewController.didFinishPlaying(notification:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                       object: player.currentItem)

self.playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

self.playerController?.player = player

self.playerController?.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true

self.playerController?.showsPlaybackControls = YES

self.playerController?.delegate = self

self.playerController?.player?.play()

self.present(self.playerController!, animated: true, completion : nil)
```

Here is the dismissal code:

```swift
// Delegate can implement this method to be notified when Picture in Picture will start.
func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    self.playerController?.dismiss(animated: NO, completion: nil )
}
```

And here's what's remaining in the systemwide media player that is shown on the lock screen / control centre:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 13 SDK ONLY:  Here's the solution, but the answer is that despite dismissing the AVPlayerViewController, the AVPlayer object that it's knows about is persistent and that needs to be set to nil.

```swift
private func killVideoPlayer()
{ 
    self.playerController?.player?.pause()
    self.playerController?.player  = nil

    self.playerController?.dismiss(animated: YES, completion: { self.playerController = nil })
}
```

Previous SDK's, this still isn't working.

Neither is setting the AVAudioSession.active to false... ?!?! Still need a pre iOS 13 SDK solution.